# Not getting in PHP Array in required format

Tags: php, mysql

The array I want is given below;

`Array ( [0] => John [1] => toby [2] => hrithik )`

I tried below code for

```html
$r = array();
$queryx = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `student` WHERE `status` = '1'") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryx)) {
$r[] = $row;
}


print_r($r);
```

The output I am getting is given below;

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => John ) [1] => Array ( [name] => toby ) [2] => Array ( [name] => hrithik ) )`

Comment: @Deep I tried but its fetching only one row and same array which I was getting earlier.

Comment: then no need to declare as array , just use as in the answer given below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryx)) {
    $r[] = $row['name'];
}
```

It will put name in `$r` array on different index like `0, 1, 2 and so on`

Answer (score 1):

try the following code below,

```
$r = array();
$i = 0;
$queryx = mysql_query("SELECT `name` FROM `student` WHERE `status` = '1'") or die ('Query is invalid: ' . mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryx)) {
$r[$i] = row["name"];
$i++;
}
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `mysql-fetch-row` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

you can refer api to check how these function works
mysql_fetch_array http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php
mysql_fetch_assoc http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php